# Почему setTimeout в цикле 10 раз выводит "10"?

Tags: javascript

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert(i);
    }, 100);
}
```

Comment: потому что так написал автор примера. захотел бы 20 - написал бы 20 :)

Comment: Я ничего не понимаю, фчём вопрос?

Comment: Подозреваю в том, что автор ожидает увидеть 1, 2, 3, 4.. но надо почитать как работает анонимная функция.

Answer (score 2):

Потому, что к моменту срабатывания `setTimeout`, цикл уже полностью выполнится и переменная примет значение равное десяти. А раз на момент вызова переменная уже равна десяти, то и на вывод пойдет десять.

Легкий пример происходящего:

```js
a = 10;
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(a);
}, 1000);
a += 20; //выполнится раньше, чем вывод
```

Для решения, Вам надо убрать зависимость и создать локальное замыкание. Поскольку в JS область видимости у функций, Вам надо создать функцию и передать ей значение на текущий момент. Тогда оно будет скопировано, а не использовано как ссылка.

```js
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      (function(i) {
            setTimeout(function(){
              console.log(i);
            }, 100);
      })(i);
    }
```

Comment: Ещё, кстати, можно упомянуть, что для того чтобы задержка была равная между всему итерациями, нужно либо время задержки делать зависящим от `i`, либо следующий `setTimeout` устанавливать по факту выполнения предыдущего.

Comment: @Regent, а есть какой-то простой способ сделать последовательное выполнение нескольких `setTimeout`, что бы он работал как в глобальной области, так будучи выполненном внутри функции? Я просто что-то никак не догадаюсь, как это сделать без глобальных переменных.

Comment: Что-то я не понял фразы _"работал как в глобальной области, так будучи выполненном внутри функции"_. Возможно, вы про [такой вариант](https://jsfiddle.net/0w5bt80d/)?

Comment: @Regent, да, я про такой вариант, спасибо.